# Highly important categorical variable with many values and only few data points per value

Tags: model-selection, many-categories

Let's say I've got a dataset of music albums. As predictors, I have the artist, the genre, the year it was made plus several others (categorical and numeric). I want to predict the number of copies sold.

Now I have a dataset of 150000 albums by 30000 artists. The difficulty in my view will be that the artist is **by far** the main driver of sales but I have only few observations per artist. Other things like genre can use the full dataset as they have an effect irrespective of the artist. I want to capture the artist specific interactions as well as the overarching effects as well as possible.

What type of regression model would be suited for this? I am familiar with linear regression, GLMs and tree ensembles. Haven't used deep learning yet but would also be open to that.

Comment: I wonder if you would be better off considering the artist a random effect.

Comment: Oh I can see I am a bit rusty. Will have to read up on random effects again, currently its not clear to me how exactly that helps in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would model this problem using a multilevel Poisson regression.

$CopiesSold_{i} \sim Poisson(\lambda_{i})$

$\lambda_{i} = \alpha[artist_{i}] + X_{i}\beta$

With this structure the intercept is changing based on the artist and other variables' effects are captured by $X\beta$. Of course you can make this even more complicated by adding non-linear effects, making the effects random, adding overdispersion or trying Negative Binomial likelihood instead of Poisson. I would fit this model using a Bayesian framework in JAGS or Rstan. **glm** in R could do it as well.

Comment: I think one major interaction will be between artist and year, since artists can become more popular over time and some fade. Is it possible in a glm to have a numeric (non-categorical) calendar year effect for each artist. What if I have only one album for a given artist? Then the intercept and the calendar year parameter cannot both be fit in a normal glm?

Comment: I can deal with such complexities using a Bayesian approach but I am not really sure if glm can handle them.